# Alternate proof of easiest special case of PBW theorem

Tags: lie-algebras, pbw-theorems

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$ (I'm happy for that field to be $\mathbb{C}$) and let $U(L)$ be its universal enveloping algebra.  One of the standard consequences of the PBW theorem is that the natural map $L \rightarrow U(L)$ is injective.  I was wondering if there are any alternate proofs of this that are easier than just proving the PBW theorem.

One trivial observation is that by the universal property of $U(L)$, this is true if there is an injective map from $L$ to any associative algebra.  This already covers a lot of the Lie algebras that appear in nature; for instance, Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ lie in the associative algebra of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: Interesting question. It's hard to imagine a proof that doesn't involve doing some computations with the Jacobi identity...

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/cayleys-theorem-for-lie-algebras) for some related discussion. My guess is that no proof avoiding PBW is known.

Comment: I don't know if it's easier than PBW in general, but for some particular instances of $L$, this is clearly much easier. Indeed, this is equivalent to showing that there is an associative algebra $(A,\cdot)$ and an injective homomorphism $L\to (A,[\cdot,\cdot])$. In particular, this is immediate when $L$ has trivial center (use the adjoint representation). More generally, this is immediate when there is a grading of $L$ in a torsion-free abelian group such that $L_0$ has trivial intersection with the center.